# Access violation writing location 0x0105100b. Assembly

Tags: exception, memory, assembly

I'm getting this error when running program:

```
Access violation writing location 0x0105100b
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code? It's breaking at `mov [ecx],dl`

```
    .686
.model flat

extern _ExitProcess@4: PROC


public _main

.data

.code
    data1 db 61H,62H,63H,64H,65H,66H,67H,68H,69H,70H,0H
    data2 db 25 dup (?)
_main:

    mov eax, OFFSET data1
    mov ecx, OFFSET data2

    mov edx, 0

    mov ebp, ecx
    sub ebp, eax ; licznik

    mov dl, BYTE PTR [eax]
    mov [ecx],dl




koniec:

    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4


END
```

Comment: By default your application does not have rights to write into the code sections.

Comment: Ahem, [I got confused](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define+tittle).

Comment: Hahahaha, thanks i think it's time to sleep. Haven't noticed that for 30m

Comment: Editing for clarity will facilitate clear answers. ;-)